# Date conversion puzzle

Tags: javascript

Getting some inconsistent results in javascript when converting dates to strings and strings to dates. This code, as noted in the comments, seems strange:

```
// Start with a string literal        
var s1 = "10/31/2014";

// Convert string to date
var f1 = s1.split("/");
var d1 = new Date(f1[2], (f1[0] - 1), f1[1]);
alert("Date from string: " + d1); // works

// Convert that date to a string
a1 = (d1.toLocaleString("en-US")).split(" ", 1);
alert("Array[0] from split: " + a1[0]); // works
s2 = a1[0];
alert("String from Array[0] assignment: " + s2);

// Convert string to date (identical to before)
var f2 = s2.split("/");
var d2 = new Date(f2[2], (f2[0] - 1), f2[1]);
alert("Date from String: " + d2); // fails: "Invalid date"
```

Anyone know why this string is not a string?

Btw, changing

```
s2 = a1[0];
```

to

```
s2 = a1[0].toString();
```

rather predictably changes nothing. Ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/pfvh6fed/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got a comma at the end of your year string, adding a `.replace(',','')` fixed the issue

```
// Start with a string literal        
var s1 = "10/31/2014";

// Convert string to date
var f1 = s1.split("/");
var d1 = new Date(f1[2], (f1[0] - 1), f1[1]);
alert("Date from string: " + d1); // works

// Convert that date to a string
a1 = (d1.toLocaleString("en-US")).split(" ", 1);
alert("Array[0] from split: " + a1[0]); // works
s2 = a1[0];
alert("String from Array[0] assignment: " + s2);

// Convert string to date (identical to before)
var f2 = s2.split("/");
var d2 = new Date(f2[2].replace(",",""), (f2[0] - 1), f2[1]);
alert("Date from String: " + d2); // ?
```

Comment: I run this on Chrome and you are 100% correct. Chrome returns a comma after 2014 and IE does not. Oddly, that's not the bug. Try it on IE and it does not have the comma and it STILL doesn't work. I may be missing something obvious but I'd think it ought to work without the comma as is the case in IE.

Comment: OK, after much debugging I have determined that there is one hell of a bug in IE.  When you make the data string, for some reason either side of each number in the date as indicated here.  `*14*/*08*/*2014*` there is a phantom character of char code `8206`.  This character is screwing up IE's parseInt() function which is part of the string to date conversion.  You give it a string, it tries to make an int but fails because of these two characters.  This could be fixed with a regexp replace, but it is much better to go with @Jofre's answer.

Comment: This can be proven by alerting the length of the date string `a1[0]`, you will see it is 6 characters longer than what is visible.  That is because of these 6 'phanton' characters that IE puts there for some stupid reason.

Comment: Unicode Left-to-Right is char 8206. Since the toLocaleString is fundamentally based on a subjective view of what is a normal representation for a given locale, I guess it could conceivably be valid to mark up the date string with Unicode directionality indicators. There must be some spec somewhere that determines what this is *supposed* to return but MarshallOfSound - you solved the puzzle :)

Answer (score 1):

If you print `console.log(f2[2]);` you'll notice that you are actually capturing `2014,`, with an included comma. Remove that and it should work properly.

EDIT: the best way to do what you are trying, however, should be the semantic way:

```
day = date.getDay() 

month = date.getMonth() 

year = date.getFullYear()
```

Comment: I think this browser stuff makes it pretty clear that you are right that the semantic way is the only reliable way. Still, I would like to know what is wrong with my code when run on IE (where there is no comma in the LocaleString).